# codeigniter cannot extends the My_Controller.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created `MY_Controller.php` in the `core folder`. I autoloaded all the `libraries` and `model` that i want in my `website`. And also put some data in the `MY_Controller.php`. but when I extend this controller by another controller the data cannot be extended in the second controller. This is `MY_Controller.php` code.

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
   public $data;
   public function __contstruct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
        $this->load->library(array('ion_auth', 'form_validation','form'));
        /*-Website Developer Information-*/

        $this->data['FullName']="Waqas Dev lover";
        $this->data['ShortName']="Dev Lover";
        $this->data['Mobile']="03049211134";
        $this->data['Version']="1.0.1";
        $this->data['Copyright']="Waqas Dev Lover";
        $this->data['Year']=date("Y");
        $this->data['DevelopedBy']="Waqas Dev Lover";
        $this->data['DevelopedByUrl']="http://www.facebook.com/xndltwaqas1";
        /* -End of Website Developer Information- */
        /*System Information */
        $this->data["SectionH1"]="Admin panel";
        /*End of System Information */

        /*User Information */
       $user_id =$this->session->userdata('user_id');
       //echo  =$this->ion_auth->logged_in();
       //exit;
        $this->data['user'] = $this->ion_auth->user($user_id)->row();
        //$this->get_user_groups($user_id);
        $this->data['group']=$this->ion_auth_model->get_users_groups($user_id)->result();
        //var_dump($this->data['group']);
        //exit();
        /*End User Information */
    }

     public function show($path,$data=NULL){
        if($data === NULL){
            $data = $this->data;
            var_dump($data); exit;
        }
        $this->load->view("template/header",$data);
        $this->load->view("template/sidebar",$data);
        $this->load->view($path,$data);
        $this->load->view("template/footer",$data);
    }  
}
?>
```

And this is the `Dashboard.php` in which I want to extends the `MY_Controller.php`. But it Won't extends the Data in the `Dashboard.php`.

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends MY_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->show("admin/home");
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at your line `__contstruct()` in your MY_Controller class - if this isn't a typo you should alter it to `__construct()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already `add`, `append` or `reset` your `$this->data` from `MY_Controller` without the need to pass extra `data` array to `show`.

```
public function show($path)
{
    $this->load->view("template/header", $this->data);
    $this->load->view("template/sidebar", $this->data);
    $this->load->view($path, $this->data);
    $this->load->view("template/footer", $this->data);
}
```

and in your dashboard you can use it directly:

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['foo'] = 'bar';
        $this->show("admin/home");
    }
}
```

you can now access `$foo` in your dashboard view